# How do I print a Multi-Character Constant in C?

Tags: c, ncurses, extended-ascii

I am trying to make a box in ncurses using ASCII values above 128. There is an extended ASCII table that goes all the way to 255, and I want to use ASCII value 176 for my border.

Unless I print the exact character in a print statement, it creates a bunch of errors.

For example:

```
wborder(local_win, '░', '░', '░', '░', '░', '░', '░', '░');
```

This should print that symbol into a box format, but instead it gives me errors for:

"warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]"

I've tried inputting the ASCII value into it instead, I've tried using variables that hold the ASCII vale, and nothing works.

Along with that, when I try printing '░' into ncurses, it doesn't print that out, it prints ~V~R.

I'd love any amount of feedback. Please let me know if you need anymore info to solve the issue

-Ryan

Comment: [some tips](https://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~heha/viewchm.php/hs/petzold.chm/petzoldi/ch02c.htm)

Comment: ░ is encoded as 3 bytes in utf8, which might explain the warning you are seeing. Can you show an example of how you did it with ASCII values?

Comment: your editor is replacing those chars with UTF-something ones. Yuo need to instruct yout editor do not so.

Comment: @jamieguinan I'm not sure I follow. I tried wborder(local_win, 176, 176, ...,176); and that just produced white space, but no error. How would I print the utf8 value?

Comment: Maybe your terminal isn't showing extended characters. See  @P__J__ 's answer and try those ACS constants. http://www.melvilletheatre.com/articles/ncurses-extended-characters/index.html

Comment: @jamieguinan yea I just gave it a try. It doesn't give an error, but it also doesn't print anything out.

Comment: "I want to use ASCII value 176" is a misnomer as [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) is only defined 0-127.  Perhaps "I want to use character value 176"?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica When I looked up an ASCII table, I was given an "extended list" ASCII table that showed 255 ASCII values.

Comment: CupcakeLove Perhaps it showed 256 [_Extended ASCII_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII)?  There are many such extensions, some more common and well specified than others.  Yet ASCII remains 128

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yea I believe it was labeled "ASCII extended table". But if it's still in relation to the ASCII symbols, then why would it not print?

Comment: CupcakeLove  Try something simple: `int i; (for i = 128; i<256; i++) printf("%d <%c>\n", i, i);` and see how your terminal interprets such characters.  Are they as hoped?  Avoid pronouns "why would it not print?": unclear what "it" you refer to and how was "not print" detected?  Was output redirect into a file or only visually assessed?

Comment: The program didn't output anything between the less than/greater than symbols. My "it" was referring to the general program not printing out the ASCII characters above 127 in the same way the program prints the ASCII characters below 128.

Answer (score 1):

Your editor is replacing them with multichar ones. You can

1. Say your editor to do not.
2. Use just integer values
3. Use hex escape codes.

Example:

```
wborder(local_win, 176, 176, 176, 176, 176, 176, 176, 176);
```

Comment: When I put that into wborder, it doesn't print anything out

Comment: sp maybe it is not 176. Maybe your terminal is not printing anything above 127, check your ACS_VLINE,
ACS_VLINE,
ACS_HLINE,
ACS_HLINE,
ACS_ULCORNER,
ACS_URCORNER,
ACS_LLCORNER,
ACS_LRCORNER.

Comment: How do I check these things? I've only recently started using ncurses so I am not fully aware of how everything works

Comment: Oh my goodness I am so stupid. I didn't realize that "ACS_VLINE" is what you wanted me to input. Yes this allowed me to print it out thank you. Should I just use all the ACS values for all ascii values above 127 then?